# AutoHotkey: While 2 keys are pressed = press 3rd key?

Tags: autohotkey

In [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), how can I do the following:

While <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> are pressed down at the same time, send <kbd>LShift</kbd> every `X` milliseconds; do this until <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> both are released.

I'm a beginner; what I tried, failed...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:  I tried:

```
w & `::
  Loop  {
    If GetKeyState("Space", "P") && GetKeyState("w", "P") {
      Send, {LShift}
      Sleep, 500
      If Not GetKeyState("Space", "P") && GetKeyState("w", "P") {  
        Pause
      }   
  }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```
; vk57 & vkC0:: ; w+tilde
Space & vk57:: ; space+w
   Loop
   {
      SendInput, % "{vkA0}" ; lshift
      Sleep, 500
   }
   ; replace "Or" with "And" keywords for to see difference
   Until, !(GetKeyState("Space", "P") Or GetKeyState("vk57", "P"))
   Return
```